# Como detectar que foi plugado o headset?

Tags: java, android

Andei observando que toda vez que "plugo" o *headset* no meu *smarphone*, aparece uma notificação do Deezer (aplicativo de *stream* de música) já dizendo para clicar e para abrir a aplicação.

De acordo com a documentação que fala sobre o [`ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG), eles recomendam usar o [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) caso a versão mínima do SDK seja o [Lollipop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#LOLLIPOP).

É preciso criar um `<receiver>` para realizar esse procedimento? Como faço para verificar o status do *headset* ou detectar se foi "plugado"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é necessário criar um BroadcastReceiver mas ele deve ser registado de forma explicita, através de `Context.registerReceiver()`, e não apenas declarado no *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Em relação ao `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`, o que a documentação refere é que, caso a versão mínima do SDK seja o Lollipop, deverá usar a constante `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` em vez da `Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`.<sup>(1)</sup>

Para saber o estado do headset verifique, no método `onReceive()` do BroadcastReceiver, a chave `state` do Extra do Intent.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch(state) {
            case(0):
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset unplugged");
                break;
            case(1):
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset plugged");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset state invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Não entendo porquê, já que, em ambas, é referido que o seu valor é `android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG`.</sub>

Comment: Porque `intent.getIntExtra("state", -1)` mesmo?

Comment: Os métodos `getXXXExtra()` recebem no 2º parâmetro um valor para ser usado/retornado caso a chave não exista.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas a título de curiosidade e para complementar a resposta do ramaral, que está excelente.

Existe a possibilidade de usar a [Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/) para detectar, quando o headset é plugado e ao mesmo tempo saber se no momento atual tem um headset plugado.

Para se obter o snapshot do estado do headset (apenas colocando a parte importante):

```
Awareness.SnapshotApi.getHeadphoneState(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<HeadphoneStateResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull HeadphoneStateResult headphoneStateResult) {
                        if (!headphoneStateResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get headphone state.");
                            return;
                        }
                        HeadphoneState headphoneState = headphoneStateResult.getHeadphoneState();
                        if (headphoneState.getState() == HeadphoneState.PLUGGED_IN) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Headphones are plugged in.\n");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Headphones are NOT plugged in.\n");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Esse exemplo ta no própria documentação: [Get headphone state](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/snapshot-get-data#get_headphone_state)

E para ser notificado, usando as [Fences API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview):

```
// Declare variables for pending intent and fence receiver.
private PendingIntent myPendingIntent;
private MyFenceReceiver myFenceReceiver;

// Initialize myPendingIntent and fence receiver in onCreate().
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION);
    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    MyFenceReceiver = new myFenceReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myFenceReceiver, new IntentFilter(FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION));
    ...
}

// Create a fence.
AwarenessFence headphoneFence = HeadphoneFence.during(HeadphoneState.PLUGGED_IN);

// Register the fence to receive callbacks.
// The fence key uniquely identifies the fence.
Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
        mGoogleApiClient,
        new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
            .addFence("headphoneFenceKey", headphoneFence, myPendingIntent)
            .build())
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fence was successfully registered.");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Fence could not be registered: " + status);
                }
            }
        });

// Handle the callback on the Intent.
public class MyFenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);

        if (TextUtils.equals(fenceState.getFenceKey(), "headphoneFenceKey")) {
            switch(fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
                case FenceState.TRUE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Headphones are plugged in.");
                    break;
                case FenceState.FALSE:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Headphones are NOT plugged in.");
                    break;
                case FenceState.UNKNOWN:
                    Log.i(TAG, "The headphone fence is in an unknown state.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Como eu disse, são formas diferentes de se resolver o mesmo problema. Mas de fato a `Fences API` exige um pouco mais de boilerplate. Mas tem a possibilidade de consultar o Snapshot de forma simples.

A grande vantagem na minha opinião é a possiblidade combinar estados.

- Quero ser notificado quando o usuário estiver com o fone e também com o celular carregando, dai eu posso sugerir uma ação X.
- Quero ser notificado quando o usuário está com o headset plugado e está correndo, posso sugerir a playlist de corrida dele.

Fazer isso usando apenas as API's do framework é muito mais difícil.

Comment: Boa, não sabia dessa possibilidade.